# Duplicate records are inserting into database with spring transaction

Tags: spring, transactions

We have 10 servers.Some flight related data will come to the servers.From servers that data will come to our application.Means same data can come to our application more than one time,but finally i need to save that data only once in the database.So we are checking in the database before inserting the data.If that record is already not exist in the database then only we are going to save the data.But for some reason we are getting duplicate records in the database.

Is it necessary using synchronization in this scenario.

What might be the problem here.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

In our company the way we deal with multiple data sources where same piece of information may go through is by utilizing batches.
What we found is by doing this at code level (java and .NET), we would invest a lot of devops time and still have duplications.

By implementing a batching process we stored everything locally and process using 2 batch jobs.
1st will ensure quality of data and remove duplications
2nd will compress and push data to our persistence service (we use XCOM to push straight into a db queue which then plugs the data in).

If you can implement something similar because you have a central point of entry upon which you can implement proper quality gates.

Hope our example helps, if not let me know happy to remove this. :)